# How to send parameters in curl in php

Tags: php, curl

How would I write below command in curl php:

> curl -XPOST https://apiv2.unificationengine.com/v2/message/send
>
> –data
>   “{ \"message\”: { \“receivers\”: [{\“name\”: \“TO_NAME \”,
>
> \“address\”: \“TO_EMAILADDRESS\” ,
>
> \“Connector\”: \“UNIQUE_CONNECTION_IDENTIFIER\”,
>
> \“type\”: \“to\”}],\“sender\”: {\“address\”: \“EMAIL_ADDRESS\”},
>
> \“subject\”:\“Hello\”,\“parts\”: [{\“id\”: \“1\”,
>
> \“contentType\”: \“text/plain\”,
>
> \“data\”:\“Hi welcome to UE\” ,
>
> \“size\”: 100,\“type\”: \“body\”,\“sort\”:0}]}}“
>
> -u USER_ACCESSKEY:USER_ACCESSSECRET -k

if this is the right way to execute and write curl in php:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://abcproject.com/tester.phtml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");

// in real life you should use something like:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
//          http_build_query(array('postvar1' => 'value1')));

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

// further processing ....
if ($server_output == "OK") { ... } else { ... }
```

Here is more sample code [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code).

But I am finding problem that where to mentions -u, --data options in php curl.

Comment: Handling cURL calls in PHP is a gruesome task. Try using something like Guzzle - http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/- instead. It will save a lot of headaches...

Comment: Do you want to post JSON data, right?

Comment: @JoseRojas I want to execute above command and want to know that how to do that. post parameters would be json I think.

Comment: That USER_ACCESSKEY:USER_ACCESSSECRET are username and password?

Comment: @JoseRojas those are user keys and user secret for my app that I have created for this api under my app.

Comment: @JoseRojas This is the url https://developer.unificationengine.com/ from where I have got this command.

Comment: @motanelu how I would convert this to guzzle command? I am confused that what -data and -u are? Are they post parameters or something else.

Comment: -data is the data that's being sent over the POST and -u are the credentials required for the authentication (you may not need those)

Comment: @motanelu On developer.unificationengine.com they have mentioned to use user secret and access keys to use api so I cannot omit them. Thanks for telling that I have to use these parameters in post but now I want to know that where to use '-u' parameters? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**curl** `-u` is equivalent to `CURLOPT_USERPWD` in php-curl.

You set it with [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php), as the others.

`--data` is `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, which you are already sending. But in your case you'd want to populate with the json you want to send.

If you are sending a JSON, you'd do well in setting the `Content-type` header (and content-length wouldn't be amiss either)

Be careful, in your example call there are some weird characters. But the JSON you posted is equivalent to:

```
$yourjson = <<<EOF
{
  "message": {
    "receivers": [
      {
        "name": "TO_NAME ",
        "address": "TO_EMAILADDRESS",
        "Connector": "UNIQUE_CONNECTION_IDENTIFIER",
        "type": "to"
      }
    ],
    "sender": {
      "address": "EMAIL_ADDRESS"
    },
    "subject": "Hello",
    "parts": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "contentType": "text/plain",
        "data": "Hi welcome to UE",
        "size": 100,
        "type": "body",
        "sort": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
EOF;
```

But usually you'd start with your data in array form and `json_encode` it.

So you'd start with something like:

```
$array = [
    'message' =>
        [
            'receivers' =>
                [
                    0 =>
                        [
                            'name'      => 'TO_NAME ',
                            'address'   => 'TO_EMAILADDRESS',
                            'Connector' => 'UNIQUE_CONNECTION_IDENTIFIER',
                            'type'      => 'to',
                        ],
                ],
            'sender'    =>
                [
                    'address' => 'EMAIL_ADDRESS',
                ],
            'subject'   => 'Hello',
            'parts'     =>
                [
                    0 =>
                        [
                            'id'          => '1',
                            'contentType' => 'text/plain',
                            'data'        => 'Hi welcome to UE',
                            'size'        => 100,
                            'type'        => 'body',
                            'sort'        => 0,
                        ],
                ],
        ],
];
```

... convert that using `$yourjson = json_encode($array)`, and that's it.

E.g.:

```
// you already have your json inside of $yourjson,
// plus your username and password in their respective variables.

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$user:$pass");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $yourjson);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
              'Content-Type: application/json',                    
              'Content-Length: ' . strlen($yourjson)
               ]
);
```

Comment: Let me try this. Thanks!

Comment: I am getting invalid character &#39;-&#39; in numeric literal in response.

Comment: That's an apostroph, or single quote. There is something wrong with your data.

Comment: YES!! You saved my day big time! Though I have to check few more urls. And invalid character &#39;-&#39; in numeric literal was there because I was sending array instead of json in post params.

Comment: Yes It did. Thank you. For current scenario it did. I was really confuse because I never used Curl before but my bad that I didn't have sufficient time to do RnD on this. I hope this question help someone in some way. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

to send data as JSON add header `content-type` and set as JSON and add the option `CURLOPT_USERPWD`, something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://apiv2.unificationengine.com/v2/message/send");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            “{ \"message\”: { \“receivers\”: [{\“name\”: \“TO_NAME \”, \“address\”: \“TO_EMAILADDRESS\” , \“Connector\”: \“UNIQUE_CONNECTION_IDENTIFIER\”, \“type\”: \“to\”}],\“sender\”: {\“address\”: \“EMAIL_ADDRESS\”},\“subject\”:\“Hello\”,\“parts\”: [{\“id\”: \“1\”,\“contentType\”: \“text/plain\”, \“data\”:\“Hi welcome to UE\” ,\“size\”: 100,\“type\”: \“body\”,\“sort\”:0}]}}“);

// in real life you should use something like:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
//          http_build_query(array('postvar1' => 'value1')));

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks Jose! Let me try both the solutions.

Comment: Thank you So much @Jose. You all saved my day!

Comment: Yes @Jose it worked. But unfortunately I can mark only one answer. I am really thankful for your great answer. For those who will look for right answer for anything like I have posted. Your answer is also 100% correct.